# Google App Engine Apis

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-bigtable

I am new to Google App Engine. I am building a web app using python and django rest api framework.  I am using cloud bigtable, cloud sql and cloud storage for my databases and storage. I wanted to know if I have to use Google App Engine Apis or can I build my own in django to read and write data to the databases and get files from cloud storage? I want to try to keep costs low and not lock in to Google App Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vanilla DjangGAE to do everything you'd mentioned.  [A good starting point](https://djangae.readthedocs.io/en/latest/db_backend/)

It's worth mentioning that there are a few notable limitations.  Those are also listed in the site I'd linked to.

Comment: Are all these thing, such as Djangae, open source and free to use in commercial products?

Comment: most definitely.

Comment: @JayBennett I was actually going to link to https://p.ota.to - a company that has been building on GAE with Django for at least 5-6 years now and after I went to their github I realized they're the maintainers of djangae, so I most definitely upvote this! If anyone knows how to run Django on GAE it's them.

Comment: Djangae current only supports django 1.7 and 1.8. Is it ok to start a new project with 1.8 even though 1.11 is the newest version of django?